# Django queryset after update() call?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After updating queryset,

```
queryset.update(quantity=F('quantity') + increment_amount)

serializer = MySerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'product': product})

serializer.data # here sometimes wrong old data
queryset.values() # shows correct data.
```

If I evaluate `queryset` (in DRF), would it contain the update I made above?

My teammate found sometimes DRF serialized data doesn't have the updated info.

But `queryset.values()` shows the correct updated info.

I can't reproduce this and we are having hard time to google.

Comment: Can you post the full serializers or at least the methods that use the product context and all? What do you mean, sometimes wrong old data? The code above is the only thing you do? and sometimes gives you old data?

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc ah I found that we are calculating the quantity when we serialize the queryset, and it may not be the raw database value... thanks for the hint... closing..

Answer (score 0):

> If I evaluate queryset (in DRF), would it contain the update I made above?

It should.

> My teammate found sometimes DRF serialized data doesn't have the updated info.

Because you don't reevaluate the queryset after performing the update.

> But queryset.values() shows the correct updated info.

Because that reevaluates the queryset.

Try with:

```
queryset.update(quantity=F('quantity') + increment_amount)

serializer = MySerializer(queryset.all(), many=True, context={'product': product})

serializer.data # Should always contain up to date data.
```